# Describe the yellow space with just 2 set operations

Tags: logic, volume

How can I describe the following yellow space with just 2 set operations?

[image]

I can only do it with 3 I thougt, but there is a way using just 2 set operations.

Comment: What is a "volume operation"?

Comment: I translated it from the german word "mengenoperation", what I ment are the basics of set theory. I assume :)

Comment: I think "set operation" would be a better translation.

Comment: thank you, my math vocabulary needs some improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what you want is the following:

$(A\cap B) \mathop \triangle C$, where $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference operator.

Answer (score 2):

$(A \cap B)\Delta C$ where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference operator.